# Potential Hack (Macbook/Edge/Teams/Remote)

Tags: macos, microsoft-edge

I have noticed earlier that my Macbook Pro camera light was lit on - the screen is turned off but not sleeping - the entire time the device was not being used or touched. I logged in to investigate and I have found that Microsoft Edge (Chromium) was on with a few tabs. The moment I tried to navigate through it, Edge broke and shutdown unexpectedly.

I opened it again, tried to access last tabs (Cmd+Shift+T) with no luck. I went through the browsing history and I have found a url for Microsoft Teams was accessed (same url was accessed some hours before with different parameters)

The very interesting thing about it, the url was accessed twice at a time when no one was using the Macbook, which i'm willing to take but the fact that it was followed by a crash made things seem a bit suspicious. Looking into the console, the only thing I was able to find in the log around the crash time is this:

`Microsoft Edge[356]: BUG in libdispatch client: mach_recv, monitored resource vanished before the source cancel handler was invoked { 0x7fad88231bf0[source], ident: 56579 / 0xdd03, handler: 0x110c94610 }`

Is there any explanation of how or why such a thing would happen? Should I be concerned?

PS: Energy Settings currently prevents the Macbook from sleeping so no worries there. But that does not explain why would it access the url randomly and crash the browser without retrieval.

Comment: if you're sure no one else used the computer, this really sounds like a remote desktop hack.  I would turn off RDP if you don't use it: https://www.securicy.com/blog/how-to-disable-remote-access-for-macos/

Comment: @pcalkins it's a Mac. I don't think you meant "RDP"...

Comment: @Hyo if your computer did things that you did not initiate, then you have lost control of the computer.

Comment: You should be worried